# Meteor.js server method queue

Tags: meteor, methods, fibers

I have a method in Meteor that takes a bit of time to execute, and this method is called a lot of times with different params.

But the client can change the params while the data is still being loaded, so I want the server to be able to clear the method queue in some way. Is that possible

So just for the example:

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getLongTimeExecutedData': function (settings, reset) {
    let self = this;
    if(reset) {
      // How to reset my entire queue here.
    }
    Meteor._sleepForMs(1000);
    let myData = { settings: settings, timestamp: new Date() };
    return myData;
  }
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.call('getLongTimeExecutedData', { param1: 'test' , param2: 1 }, false);
Meteor.call('getLongTimeExecutedData', { param1: 'test' , param2: 2 }, false);
Meteor.call('getLongTimeExecutedData', { param1: 'test' , param2: 3 }, false);
...
// Reset queue on server with true here
Meteor.call('getLongTimeExecutedData', { param1: 'test2' , param2: 1 }, true);
Meteor.call('getLongTimeExecutedData', { param1: 'test2' , param2: 2 }, false);
Meteor.call('getLongTimeExecutedData', { param1: 'test2' , param2: 3 }, false);
...
```

I don't want to use this.unblock(), because the method is using a MS SQL connection, and if it still executes, it takes up a lot of unwanted request to the server.

Hope somebody have some ideas? :)

// Peter

Answer (score 0):

there are several job queue projects available for this

https://github.com/artwells/meteor-queue

https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection

Comment: Is the only way to control this, by adding all my method calls into a Collection first? Just think that's a wierd approach to this. Besides, I dont want the jobs to get stacked... I want each client to have their own stack, but just want to be able to cancel all unwanted request in the stack.